# Angular JS. I am attempting to filter a simple list of results using check boxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am attempting to allow my users to filter my results array using check boxes.

I am just getting in to the Angular JS frame work and not quite sure how to approach my scenario.

I am trying to work out if what I am doing is possible in the way I am approaching it or do I simply need to write a custom filter function.

I have put together a simple jsfiddle to illustrate my issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/arkleyjoe/7jUp6/

Here is the mark up:

```
<div ng-app="">
<div ng-init="friends = [{name:'John', phone:'555-1276'},
                       {name:'Mary', phone:'800-BIG-MARY'},
                       {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321'},
                       {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678'},
                       {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765'}]"></div>Exclude Johns
<input ng-model="search.name" name="name" type="checkbox"
ng-true-value="!John" ng-false-value="">
<br>Exclude Adams
<input ng-model="search.name" name="name" type="checkbox"
ng-true-value="!Adam" ng-false-value="">
<br>
<table id="searchObjResults">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:search">
                <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
                <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
                <tr>
</table>
</div>
```

In this example I am using check boxes to filter certain names from my list. It works fine if I select one or the other but I want to select both. Angular JS is obviously doing something behind the scenes here because it actually prevents me having two boxes selected.

Comment: I have been tinkering further based on Chandermani comments and here is what i ended up with http://jsfiddle.net/arkleyjoe/yw9NS/16/

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to bind a single property `search.name` for both the check boxes, so checking one of them would override the value set by the other one. If you want to filter on both check box values you need to assign the ng-model expression to different model properties.

You can create a method on the controller and pass it to the `filter` expression, this method would be called one time for each item in the list. If the function returns true the item is added to the end result. You can write your custom filter expression here. See filter documentation [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter)